# Find time constant in a decay exponential curve

Tags: python, scipy, curve-fitting, lti

I am trying to find the time constant to a decay exponential curve, but my code below is not working. Anybody could help? Thanks!

```
from scipy.signal import lti
import pylab as plt
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
import math as m

def model1(x, gain1, tau1):
    y = lti(gain1, [tau1, 1]).step(T=x)[1]
    return y

def get_time_constants(time_vector, power_vector):
    time_constant = []
    for i in range(len(power_vector)):
        # fit to output and estimate  parameters - gain and tau
        par1 = curve_fit(model1, time_vector[i], power_vector[i])
        print(par1)
        y_fit = model1(time_vector[i], par1[0][0], par1[0][1])

        time_constant.append(par1[0][1])
        time_constant_mean = sum(time_constant) / len(time_constant)
        plt.plot(time_vector[i], power_vector[i])
        plt.plot(time_vector[i], y_fit, label='Time Constant: %.2f s' %par1[0][1])
        plt.show()
power = [[315.04, 315.025, 275.255, 170.92, 65.89, 40.92, 25.38, 9.45, 5.835, 2.2, 1.335, 0.79, 0.24]]
time = [[0.0, 1.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 7.0, 8.0, 10.0, 11.0, 12.0, 14.0, 15.0, 17.0]]

get_time_constants(time, power)
```

[image]

Comment: What are the blue and the orange curves supposed to mean? Neither of them looks like an exponential decay.

Comment: And what exactly do you mean by "is not working"?

Comment: blue curve is the empirical data with the exponential decay..the orange curve is the "fitting curve"

Comment: I cannot judge if your way of modelling an exponential decay with `scipy.signal.lti` is correct. Did you try simply using something like `gain1 * np.exp(-tau1 * x)`?

Comment: I did, it says: "TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'numpy.float64'"